# how to remove data:;base64, from base64 String using regex in java?

Tags: java, regex, base64

I have a base64 String `"data:;base64,eyJiYXRjaFByb21vIjoiZmF"`, I need to remove the type from String i.e `data:;base64,` need to be removed. Can some help me with regex pattern for this

Comment: What's wrong with `/data:;base64,/`?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this.

```
String text = "data:;base64,eyJiYXRjaFByb21vIjoiZmF";
String unwantedText = "data:;base64,";

text = text.replace(unwantedText, "");

System.out.println(text);
```

**Output:**

```
eyJiYXRjaFByb21vIjoiZmF
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used `text = text.replaceAll(".*,", "");` This will remove everything before ,

Answer (score 0):

If the removed string occurs at the beginning of the string,here's how you remove it.

```
String s = "data:;base64,eyJiYXRjaFByb21vIjoiZmF";
 Pattern findData = Pattern.compile("(data:;base64,)*(.+)");
 Matcher getData = findData.matcher(s);
 if(getData.matches()){
 System.out.println(getData.group(2));
 }
```